# How to implement a way to remove pairs in array

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm

I'm working on a problem that requires me to remove "pairs" (north-south and east-west pairs) in an array of strings. I'm unsure of a way to approach this problem on Python.

Here's the problem:

> Write a function dirReduc which will take an array of strings and returns an array of strings with the needless directions removed (W<->E or S<->N side by side). *(link to problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/550f22f4d758534c1100025a)*

Some test inputs and outputs:

```
Input  : ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
Output : ["WEST"]

Input  : ["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"]
Output : ["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"]
```

The 2nd set of inputs and outputs don't make much sense in regards to the task. My initial thought was to use a stack, but now I'm unsure of how to do it.

Comment: Try using a dict which keeps track of occurrences of each direction

Comment: It's interesting that `["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"]` isn't `[]` since you just walked in circle and are back where you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation could just use a dictionary to define the opposing directions. When processing the list, if the current direction opposes the last one, remove the last one from the output. Else, add the new direction to the list:

```
dirs = {'NORTH': 'SOUTH', 'SOUTH': 'NORTH', 'EAST': 'WEST', 'WEST': 'EAST'}

def dirReduc(input):
    output = []

    for dir in input:
        if output and output[-1] == dirs[dir]:
            output.pop()
        else:
            output.append(dir)

    return output

print(dirReduc(["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]))
print(dirReduc(["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"]))
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you! I have no idea why I never thought of using dictionaries for pairings.